# Multiclass classification for n classes with number of output neurons = ceiling of log2 (n)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Suppose I want to use a multilayer perceptron to classify 3 classes. When it comes to number of output neurons, anybody would instantly say - use 3 output neurons with softmax activation. But what if I use 2 output neurons with sigmoid activations to output [0,0] for class 1, [0,1] for class 2 and [1,0] for class 3? Basically getting a binary encoded output with each bit being output by each output neuron. Wouldn't this technique decrease output neurons(and hence number of parameters) by a lot? A 100 class word classification for simple NLP application would require 100 output neurons for softmax where as you can cover it with 7 output neurons with the above technique. One disadvantage is that you won't get the probability scores for all the classes. My question is, is this approach correct? If so, would you consider it to be more efficient than softmaxing for datasets with large number of classes?

Comment: Doing so you are asking to your network not only to learn to classify something but also to convert the output in binary all this decreasing the number of parameters. Modern neural networks have millions of parameters having 100 output is not a big problem at all, it's just a single Nx100 matrix multiplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this, but then you would have to rethink your loss function. The cross-entropy loss used in training a model for classification is the likelihood of a categorical distribution, which assumes you have a probability associated with every class. The loss function requires 3 output probabilities and you only have 2 output values.

However, there are ways to do it anyway: you could use a binary cross-entropy loss on each element of your output, but this would be *a different probabilistic assumption* about your model. You'd be assuming that your classes have some shared characteristics `[0,0]` and `[0,1]` share a value. The decreased degrees of freedom are probably going to give you marginally worse performance (but other parts of the MLP may pick up the slack).

If you're really worried about the parameter cost of the final layer, then you might be better just not training it at all. [This paper](https://openreview.net/forum?id=S1Dh8Tg0-) shows a fixed Hadamard matrix on the final layer is as good as training it.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for pointing me to the paper :)